# How to start Timer in different time so that they dont get aligned after a while

Tags: c#

I have multiple timers (System.timers.Timer) that do multiple tasks in specified intervals when a button is clicked.

As these timers have different intervals, I do not want them to align at the same point after a while.

So, How can I start timers at different time or start one while anither one is waiting for next event to elapsed...........

Using offset or comparing with system clock? Sample code would be appreciated

Comment: Instead of spinning up one timer for each, either use a library for dealing with recurring events (such as [Quartz.net](https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/)) or write a simple one based on a priority queue, then you would have one thread/timer monitoring this queue and spinning up tasks to perform the items when they are due, and then reschedule the same item at a later time.

Comment: This seems to me that you'd be better off using one timer and a state machine.  One timer can't affect another timer unless you start fiddling with the settings for the second timer in the first timers `TimerElapsed` handler.  And that strikes me as a great way of losing control over what happens when in your application.

Comment: Also bear in mind that if the intervals aren't prime in nature and not equal, they most likely will align at some point, why is that a problem? Would you simply postpone one item a bit further then?

Comment: Its a problem because I am sending messages through a buss which gets full after a while when all messages or timers align at the same time

Answer (score 0):

http://reactivex.io/

http://www.introtorx.com/

Rx.Net is a great tool for situation like this.

For example:

```
Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)) //do job with 1 second interval
    .Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)) // start after 5 seconds
    .ObserveOn(this) // actually do it on ui thread(winform), for wpf, use ObserveOnDispatcher
    .Do(_ => DoYourJobHere())
    .Subscribe() //start every thing
```